# "bash: !/bin/su": event not found"

Tags: bash, quoting, command-history, special-characters

I have line in script which is working, but not working from command line.

```
echo "User ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers



[user@localhost ~]$ echo "test ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
bash: !/bin/su": event not found
[user@localhost ~]$
```

Edit: I am trying to add a sudo user with no permission to `su` command and sudo user have password less access to root using `sudo -i`. I was just checking each command in that script, to see how they work in command line.

I found a workaround for this in command line, that I have to use `"'!'"/bin/su`. So can someone help to explain why this didn't work in command line?

Comment: First of all, why are you editing `sudoers` file in this fashion instead of `visudo` ? second,  it's wrong format - no need for `!` . Third, it should be `username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/someprogram` , no comma. I've no idea what you're trying to do here, but  it's wrong approach in the first place.  If your `test` user gets compromised, you basically give attacker access to `su` binary

Comment: I was not sure `visudo` will work with script(will it work?). `!` which I believe will negate the command followed by that and user won't be able to execute it. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: @FoodPanda You never want to script edits against `/etc/sudoers`. It's a file that you, as the admin, should edit manually and carefully... with `visudo`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: It was a server hardening script which will add a new user and disable root access.

Comment: @FoodPanda A new user doesn't by default have root access anyway, and no access to `sudo` either. Adding that line to `sudoers` will _give_ them root access through `sudo`, and the possibility to edit the `sudoers` file themselves (if I'm reading it right).

Comment: `su` does not give special powers to root. So preventing someone with root capabilities from using it is pointless.

Answer (score 6):

[Please read carefully the comments that go with your question as it appears that you are not doing things the right way with `sudo`]

In `bash`, there is a mechanism called "history substitution" which is enabled on the command line. It allows you to insert all or part of a previous command (hence the "history") in the command you are editing.

The character that triggers history substitution is `!`. For example `!WORD` is replaced with the last command beginning with `WORD`. If you have no such command, `bash` will complain with the error message you got: `bash: !WORD: event not found`.

If you have to type a `!` without activating the history substitution mechanisme, you have to either escape it `\!` or enclose it with single quotes `'!'`.

For example: `echo 'User ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su' | ...`

If history expansion is troublesome for you, you can also disable it with `set +H`, type your commands without quoting the `!`, and re-enable it later with `set -H`.

Comment: For completeness: you can turn off history expansion in interactive bash with `set +H` but IME this is more troublesome than quoting the `!`

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085, I have added this to my answer

Answer (score 2):

1. `su` does not give special powers to root. So preventing someone with root capabilities from using it is pointless.
2. Only edit `sudo` files with `visudo`: create a new `sudo` file to augment the original and put it in `/etc/sudoers.d/`.
3. You need to escape the `!`: `"bla bla bla \! bla bla"` or `'bla bla bla ! bla bla'`. Single quote will stop **all** evaluations of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is will not help you to prevent the user with `sudo` privilege to execute `su` command, because any user with `sudo` privilege can copy the `su` from it's default directory then execute it, as always you can't give a user a full `sudo` privilege then prevent him from doing specific things, because he will always find a way to get around the restriction, you have to do it in the opposite, give him some privilege.